# exponential number generator c++, sometimes returns inf

Tags: c++

I am making a simulation and i used a function to generate numbers that mimic a exponential distribution (i dont want to use the c++ 11 functions)

This is the code

```
long double exponential(long double l)
{

long double mean = l;
long double u = ((long double)rand() / ((long double)RAND_MAX + 1.0));
return (-log(u) * mean);
}
```

Sometimes the returned value is inf, any ideas why , could it be that 0 turns out somehow?

Comment: Well (long double)rand() can always generate a number close to 0, or 0 , thus u = 0, thus you're returning log(0) * mean.

Comment: well what should i do to fix this? Have it recalculate if u> 0.99 or u< - 0.099 or u=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how you define it, `u` might be zero if (the numerator, `(long double)rand()` is 0)

*EDITED*

Try :

```
long double exponential(long double l)
{
int NUM_TRIES = 1000; // How many times to mine a non zero u before giving up?
long double mean = l;
long double DEF  = 1; // Put your default value here
long double u;
do { 
    u = ((long double)rand() / ((long double)RAND_MAX + 1.0));
}while(u == 0 && NUM_TRIES--);
if(NUM_TRIES == 0) { 
    return DEF;

} else if(u != 0) { 
  return (-log(u) * mean);
}
```

Comment: Do you hate `do ... while()` loops? :)

Comment: ty this seems to have done the trick , will check it correct when time passes :)

Comment: So that if you are incredibly unlucky you might loop forever?

Comment: @Jefffrey True. fixed.

Comment: Wow, so now sometimes we return `1` (which is not even in the original range)?

Comment: @Jefffrey I don't remember stating that the default value should not be changed, and should be kept what I have written. See my comment in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's logical and fine result. Per function [`log(arg)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log):

> Range error occurs if arg is ​`0`​. `-HUGE_VAL` is returned in that case.

For zero values returned by `rand()`, you have that *range error* and also `inf` (infinite) value.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `rand`

The `rand` function [is considered evil in this and many other cases](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Since you are lucky of be working with C++, why not take advantage of the beautiful new features of the `<random>` header?

You'll just need to use `std::uniform_real_distribution` and you are settled:

```
std::random_device rnd_dev;
std::mt19937 gen(rnd_dev());
long double precision = 0.000001;
std::uniform_real_distribution<long double> dis(precision, 1.0 - precision);
std::cout << dis(gen) << '\n';
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb37e957207f181b)'s a live example.

---

### If you still want to use `rand`

The problem clearly lies in `rand` returning `0`, and leading to `u` being `0` as well. In that case `log` will return `-inf` as stated in your question.

The solution is to see what is the closest number to `0` that you are allowing with:

```
long double u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
```

(rewritten code, since the result [is always a floating number](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bafb010b38b4527a) anyway), which is:

```
long double precision = 1 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
```

From there it's easy to see that the number that we want to generate is between `precision` and `1.0 - precision`, which is easily done with:

```
long double precision = 1 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
long double random = rand();
if (random == 0) random = precision;
long double u = random / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
```

fixing the case of having `0`.

Of course, the random distribution is not uniform anymore, because the chance of `u` being `precision` are almost twice the probability of any other number. But this is a problem that you had previously anyway (see first link).